# Docker's confusing local host ip address

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

[image]

Can Some tell me the difference between the two highlighted containers?

127.0.0.1:27017 corresponds to which container?

Also, I have deployed these apps on a digital ocean server if I want to access these 2 containers with a public IP address how's it possible? Like IP: port corresponds to which container?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the port exposing. The second one has a port exposing to your local address `0.0.0.0:27017`. The first one in the list not.